# Automate ssh commands with python

Tags: python, linux, ssh

So everyday, I need to login to a couple different hosts via ssh and run some maintenance commands there in order for the QA team to be able to test my features.

I want to use a python script to automate such boring tasks. It would be something like:

- ssh host1
- deploy stuff
- logout from host1
- ssh host2
- restart stuff
- logout from host2
- ssh host3
- check health on stuff
- logout from host3
- ...

It's killing my productivity, and I would like to know if there is something nice, ergonomic and easy to implement that can handle and run commands on ssh sessions programmatically and output a report for me.

Of course I will do the code, I just wanted some suggestions that are not bash scripts (*because those are not meant for humans to be read*).

Comment: Well-written shell code will probably be easier to read than the equivalent Python here, because it will be doing what it is meant to do: run other programs.

Comment: If you need to run the same commands on different hosts, the fabric package useful - http://www.fabfile.org/

Comment: You mean like [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) or [Rundeck](http://rundeck.org/)? There are literally hundreds

Comment: @pjames I took a look on that one, unfortunately they are not the same commands :C

Comment: @ChristianEichelmann I was looking for something more portable, like running a shell script, but easier to maintain than a shell script.

Comment: @RicardoE create a shell script if you are on unix based system or a batch script for windows. You may achieve this in python via using `fabric`, `paramiko` library, but creating the equivalent shell script would be easier *in my opinion*

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following things programmatically:

- For low-level SSH automation - [Paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/)
- For somewhat higher-level automation - [Fabric](http://fabfile.org)

Alternatively, if your activities are all around automation of typical sysadmin tasks - have a look at orchestration tools:

- [Ansible](https://github.com/ansible/ansible)
- [Saltstack](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/)

To give an example in Fabric, define a task to login to a host and run `uname -a`:

```
from fabric import *
from fabric.api import *

env.hosts = ['localhost']

def login_to_host_and_run_uname():
    run('uname -a')
```

You can run it as a standalone fabric command:

```
[none][20:03:32] vlazarenko@alluminium (~/tests)$ fab -f fab.py login_to_host_and_run_uname
[localhost] Executing task 'login_to_host_and_run_uname'
[localhost] run: uname -a
[localhost] Passphrase for private key:
[localhost] out: Darwin alluminium 16.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.5.0: Tue Jan 31 18:57:20 PST 2017; root:xnu-3789.50.195.1.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
[localhost] out:


Done.
Disconnecting from localhost... done.
```

Fabric also supports easy wrappers for `sudo()`, caches and works with SSH keys, etc, etc. Allows for easy task parallelisation over multiple hosts and so on.

Comment: @jarcobi889 check out the example I've added :)

Answer (score 4):

Could you set up a Cron job or similar on those hosts?  That would probably be ideal.

If you don't have the permission to set up Cron jobs, I use a library called [paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/).  The code goes like this:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.connect(host, port=p, timeout=2)
cmd = "ls"
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
for line in stdout.readlines():
    print(line)
ssh.close()
```

Comment: I personally find Paramiko to be a bit tedious. Fabric wrapper around it makes things much more concise.

Comment: I'll give Fabric a try next time I need to use it, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score -1):

If these manual stuffs is too many, then I may look into some server configuration managements like Ansible.

I have done this kinda automation using:

1. Ansible
2. Python Fabric
3. Rake